# How to extract the maximum value key from an array?

Tags: jmeter

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szHJJ.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oic4.png
There is an array, you need to pull the maximum value and its key from it. Each number from the array has its own key, and I need to pull exactly the one that is associated with the maximum number. With the help of regularity, I pulled out the numbers and through jsr 223, the sampler found the maximum number. Now the question is: how to extract the key of exactly the maximum number? Don't kick, a week since I started studying jmeter after lr, so I'm suffering. And the text was translated into English through a translator.

The key itself from part of the array (what needs to be pulled): dUUyTlFoUmhQMmExbCtFZ2VCY09uQT09LS1FK3lZbzJlakFUeEJoNlhCV3poRzV3PT0=--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0 described above the way to find the maximum number, in my case
the number 69, now i need to somehow find the key to the maximum number and then apply it in the request.

**Part of the array:**

````
dUUyTlFoUmhQMmExbCtFZ2VCY09uQT09LS1FK3lZbzJlakFUeEJoNlhCV3poRzV3PT0=--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="challenger_order_selected_duuytlfoumhqmmexbctfz2vcy09uqt09ls1fk3lzbzjlakfueejonlhcv3porzv3pt0--4814f46102fd5ecaf9f440be0a8925644927b3d0">69</label></span></div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the value and even highlighted it in blue, just [iterate](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp) through existing [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values, get the match number and get the key which corresponds to the match number.

Example code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < (vars.get('maxValue_matchNr') as int); i++) {
    if (vars.get('maxValue_' + i + '_g2').equals(vars.get('maxValue_max'))) {
        vars.put('maxKey_max', vars.get('maxValue_' + i + '_g1'))
        break;
    }
}
```

You should be able to refer the extracted value as `${maxKey_max}` where required.

Also [using "regularity" for getting the values from HTML might not be the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), maybe it worth considering using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead?